non-bidirectional messages between chats
I'm trying to achieve bidirectionality of messages, but messages from Chat B are not displayed in Chat A and I don't understand why, if it's a server or client side problem
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.responses import HTMLResponse
from starlette.websockets import WebSocketDisconnect
from starlette.routing import Route, WebSocketRoute, Mount
from starlette.staticfiles import StaticFiles
import base64

connected_websockets = {}

async def websocket_endpoint(websocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    connected_websockets[id(websocket)] = websocket
    try:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
            if data.startswith('ChatA:'):
                # Handle message from Chat A
                data = data[6:]  # Remove the prefix
                for ws_id, ws in connected_websockets.items():
                    if ws_id != id(websocket):
                        await ws.send_text(f"Received from ChatA: {data}")
            elif data.startswith('ChatB:'):
                # Handle message from Chat B
                data = data[6:]  # Remove the prefix
                for ws_id, ws in connected_websockets.items():
                    if ws_id != id(websocket):
                        await ws.send_text(f"Received from ChatB: {data}")
            elif data.startswith('data:'):
                # This is a data URL, handle it as a file
                await handle_file(data, websocket)
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        del connected_websockets[id(websocket)]
        
async def handle_file(data_url, websocket):
    # Extract the file type and data from the URL
    file_type, data = data_url.split(';')[0].split('/')[1], data_url.split(',')[1]
    # Decode the base64 data
    file_data = base64.b64decode(data)
    # Now you can save the file data to a file, or do whatever you want with it
    with open('received.' + file_type, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(file_data)
    await websocket.send_text(f"File received: received.{file_type}")

routes = [
    WebSocketRoute("/ws", websocket_endpoint),
    Mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")  # Aggiungi questa linea
]

app = Starlette(routes=routes)

client side
var socketA = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8001/ws');
var socketB = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8001/ws');
var fileToSend = null;

$('#form-send').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (fileToSend) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var contents = e.target.result;
            console.log('Sending file from ChatA: ', fileToSend.name); // Log added
            socketA.send(contents);
            $('#sent-messages').append($('<li>').text('Sent: ' + fileToSend.name));
            fileToSend = null;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(fileToSend);
    } else {
        var message = 'ChatA:' + $('#input-send').val();
        console.log('Sending message from ChatA: ', message); // Log added
        socketA.send(message);
        $('#sent-messages').append($('<li>').text('Sent: ' + message));
        $('#input-send').val('');
    }
});

socketA.onmessage = function(event){
    var msg = event.data;
    console.log('Received message at ChatA: ', msg); // Log added
    if (msg.startsWith('File received:')) {
        var filename = msg.split(': ')[1];
        $('#received-messages').append($('<li>').html('Received: <a href="' + filename + '" download>' + filename + '</a>'));
    } else {
        $('#received-messages').append($('<li>').text('Received: ' + msg));
    }
};

$('#form-receive').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var message = 'ChatB:' + $('#input-receive').val();
    console.log('Sending message from ChatB: ', message); // Log added
    socketB.send(message);
    $('#received-messages').append($('<li>').text('Sent: ' + message));
    $('#input-receive').val('');
});

socketB.onmessage = function(event){
    var msg = event.data;
    console.log('Received message at ChatB: ', msg); // Log added
    if (msg.startsWith('File received:')) {
        var filename = msg.split(': ')[1];
        $('#received-messages').append($('<li>').html('Received: <a href="' + filename + '" download>' + filename + '</a>'));
    } else {
        $('#received-messages').append($('<li>').text('Received: ' + msg));
    }
};

var dropZone = document.getElementById('sent-messages');

dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
});

dropZone.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
        fileToSend = files[0];
        $('#input-send').val('File: ' + fileToSend.name);
    }
});

As you can see from the image the messages sent from chat A are displayed in chat B, but the messages sent from chat B are not displayed in chat A, but are displayed in the same chat, which is a problem


Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing. And in JavaScript you could use alert() or console.log() and check messages in DevTools in Firefox/Chrome - in tab Console
